# Why does changing a variable name alter behavior of prompt()

Tags: javascript

An *extremely* simple example of using `prompt` goes as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
    <script>
        var name = prompt("Please enter your name");
        if (name != null) {
            console.log('problem!!!');
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

With this code, whether you click OK, click Cancel, or close the prompt box by clicking the cross -- in all cases you see `problem!!!` in Chrome dev tools. But if you change `name` to something else...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
    <script>
        var randomName = prompt("Please enter your name");
        if (randomName != null) {
            console.log('problem!!!');
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

...then `problem!!!` ONLY shows up if you click OK. How is that possible? Why does changing variable name change behavior of `prompt` function?

Comment: you should test with `true/false` or empty string `""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name` is global variable on `window`
and `var name` is not reset or redeclare it. It's still refer to `window.name`.

And you cannot set `window.name = null`.
DOM will make it `"null"` instead because it's have to be `string` as in the DOM spec.

```
var name;
console.log( typeof name ); //<- you got "string here"
name = null;
console.log( typeof name ); //<- you still got "string here"
console.log( name );        //<- you got string "null" not null
```

to avoid this problem ES6 introduce `let` instead.

```
let name;
console.log( typeof name ); //<- you got "undefined"
name = null;
console.log( typeof name ); //<- you got "object"
console.log( name );        //<- you got null as expected.
```

see this for more information [What's the difference between using "let" and "var" to declare a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable)

Answer (score 3):

You might be running in a "better to avoid" identifier problem:
[See here](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm)

On Chrome and Edge (14) attempting to set `name` as the result of `prompt` (after esc, cancel, x) results in `name` being set to the string `"null"`, instead of `null`. IE 11 sets `name` to null.

But if you actually press OK then `name` is set to whatever you typed.

Other variables names actually are set to `null` as the result of esc,cancel,x.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that "name" is a global hoisted from the global window. The default value is "", which is not null.
The first form has name defined even if the user hits cancel (it simply won't reset it).
The second form uses a variable that is not already defined, so it will get the value null if canceled.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are creating `name` variable in global scope but there is already `name` property present in `window` scope which is the default scope. You can check that property using

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'name')
```

Here you can see that name has its own `getter` and `setters` thus even if you assign any value to it, its setter will convert it to string. Thus

```
name = 34; // will save '34' to it not Integer
```

Where as in second case `randomNumber` variable is not defined in `global` or `window` scope thus that works as expected.

In your case `name` was being set to `null` but was getting saved as `string` i.e.

```
name; // 'null'
```

Thus your `if` was not getting executed properly.

For more read on `name` property of `window` read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/name).